# Text mining between a data frame column and 2 lists in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, text-mining, rdata

So i created two lists composed of words :

```
fruits <- c("banana","apple","strawberry")
homemade <- c("kitchen","homemade","mom","dad","sister")
```

And here is my dataset

| description | isCake |
| --- | --- |
| apple cake cooked by mom | YES |
| pie from the bakery | NO |
| strawberry dessert by dad | NO |

I want to create a text mining code so that when df$description contains one or multiple words from "fruits" AND one or multiple words from homemade, df$isCake become "OK"

**Expected output**

| description | isCake |
| --- | --- |
| apple cake cooked by mom | YES |
| pie from the bakery | NO |
| strawberry dessert by dad | OK |

```
df <- df %>% mutate(isCake=ifelse(description %in% fruits & description %in% homemade, "OK", isCake))
```

I have no error messages but apparently is doesn't work because when i subset if isCake=="OK" i always have 0 obs.

Comment: Row 1 has 'apple' and 'mom' shouldn't that be 'OK' as well?

Comment: Yeah maybe i choose a wrong example here haha, but what i meant generally speaking is that i want to qualify for "isCake" when words from both 2 lists are present in the "description" variable and that "cake" is not directly written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a pattern from `fruits` and `homemade` vector and use it in `grepl` :

```
df$isCake[grepl(paste0(fruits, collapse = '|'), df$description) & 
          grepl(paste0(homemade, collapse = '|'), df$description)] <- 'OK'

df
#                description isCake
#1  apple cake cooked by mom     OK
#2       pie from the bakery     NO
#3 strawberry dessert by dad     OK
```